# How to make a list view builder inside a Row inside a column

Tags: android, flutter, row, dynamic-columns

I would like to add a row holds containers using [list view builder] and when the row holds 3 containers , the next container go to another row { i mean that [column [has a row [has containers of max 3] ] ] and i who control with the number of containers  and this is the code that i want to modify

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWvUC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think GridView is what ur looking for.

```
GridView.count(
  // Will create 3 columns, each column will contain 1 element per row.
  // This will create a 3 elements per row impression.
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
  children: List.generate(100, (index) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        'Item $index',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
      ),
    );
  }),
);
```

Please, implement this snippet to see if it creates the layout u want, if it does, just adapt it to display the widgets you desire.

font: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists